# Unity Vertex Shaders - Gradient color that rotates around the texture's center

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

Heyas there,

I am trying to achieve a gradient shader that rotates the color around the center, just like this one on [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mt2XDK), but this one is a fragment shader

This is my first experience with shaders, and I've been studying for two days now, but I have trouble translating and getting used to many terms in linear algebra, and I haven't get a touch of it since native spoken school lessons.

So I have rotation matrix that I pass through a script:

```
public class RotationMatrix : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public Vector2 texPivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Renderer _renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    protected void Update()
    {
        Matrix4x4 t = Matrix4x4.TRS(-texPivot, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Time.time * rotationSpeed);
        Matrix4x4 r = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, rotation, Vector3.one);

        Matrix4x4 tInv = Matrix4x4.TRS(texPivot, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
        _renderer.material.SetMatrix("_Rotation", tInv * r * t);
    }
}
```

In a shader that rotates the vertices like this:

```
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float4 _MainTex_ST;
    fixed4 _Color;
    fixed4 _Color2;
    fixed  _Scale;
    float4x4 _Rotation;

    struct v2f {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        fixed4 color : COLOR;
        float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    v2f vert(appdata_full v)
    {
        v2f o;
        o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
        v.texcoord.xy = mul(_Rotation, v.texcoord.xy);
        o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
        o.color = lerp(_Color, _Color2, v.texcoord.x * _Scale);

        return o;
    }

    fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
    {
        float4 color;
        color.rgb = i.color.rgb;
        color.a = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv).a * i.color.a;
        return color;
    }


        ENDCG
    }
    }
```

Note that this is really a Frankenstein code that I crafted up from tutorials and forum posts, as everything is new to me in Cg/HLSL.

Here is what I get: [Sorry for the eye cancer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdX-yN3G-eQ&feature=youtu.be)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code works just as expected, except that the rotation occurs around the origin of the UV coordinates of the quad (0,0), which is in a corner. Considering your UVs are normalized you just need to **offset before and after the transformation.**

side note on optim: you probably don't need to set the matrix from code every frame, you can just create it on the fly in the shader since you can access a global _Time parameter.

```
half2 Rotate2D(half2 _in, half _angle) {
    half s, c;
    sincos(_angle, s, c);
    float2x2 rot = { c, s, -s, c };
    return mul(rot, _in);
}
```

thus your rotationSpeed parameter can be a material constant